# Return True if a String In one Dateframe is in Multiple Columns of Another Dataframe (Time Complexity)

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I have a 2 dataframes below. My goal is to check if the values of column df['A'] are in multiple columns of the second dataframe df2['B'] or df2['C'] and to return true or false if the value is present. Column **test** is my output column.

**df**

```
A       test     
q       True 
w       False
e       True
```

**df2**

```
B       C     
q       r 
g       r
g       e
```

My current code below works, however it is very slow working with hundreds and thousands of lines. I am using the `list` method in this case below to convert the 2 columns of df2 to list and check if the strings are in those list. However i need something much faster than this.

```
listb = df2['B'].to_list()
listc = df2['C'].to_list()

df['test'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x in (listb or listc) else 'False')
```

I have been trying to use the `.isin()` method but cant seem to get it to work with multiple columns for searching multiple columns in a separate datasets. This codes run however returns all False which is incorrect.

```
df['test'] = df['A'].isin(df2[['B','C']]).any(axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isin` after you ravel the other DataFrame. Or `np.in1D`. Assign the result back to `df['test']`.

```
np.in1d(df1['A'], df2)
#array([ True, False,  True])

df['A'].isin(df2.to_numpy().ravel())
#0     True
#1    False
#2     True
#Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Wait perhaps I'm not understanding the question I would think it would still be `[True, False, True]` in that case, because the mask is based on whether the value in A is found anywhere in B or C, and `2` is still not anywhere in those 6 values

Comment: @aloz this is correct. I am looking to see if that value is anywhere in the 2 columns. so there would be a search of 6 total values. i had to change the question because my data is in text format not numbers. sorry about this.

Comment: @Alollz thanks! your code is still running i am really wondering why i cant use a simple .isin() method for multiple columns

Comment: @JamesScott if it's still slow you can try using `.isin(np.unique(df2.to_numpy().ravel()))`. If you have many repeated values that might speed things up.

Comment: @JamesScott when you use a DataFrame as the `values` for `.isin` it requires alignment on both the index and the columns. You really don't want that alignment, so you can't use a DataFrame. You just want the array so that it checks for a value **anywhere** in the DataFrame, not just on the row or row and column when using a Series or DataFrame respectively as the values.

Comment: @Alollz df['test'] = df['A'].isin(np.unique(dfabprac.to_numpy().ravel())) is this corrrect? i got an error with it

Comment: @JamesScott yes that should be it. If you only need to check specific columns you could select only those columns with `dfabprac[list_of_cols].to_numpy()`

Comment: @ALollz ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object. This is hte error i got, i am working with all text. does this mean that there is a column with a boolean data type?